Using Hashmap in karate feature file giving PolyglotException exception
I am trying to use hashmap in the karate feature file as given below

And trying to put in the data to the hashmap using the hashmap.put method as shown below.

Post running my test via the runner.java file, i see the error "org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (put) on {} failed due to: Unknown identifier: put".
I could see some examples on how hashmap is being used in the .java files but could not find examples where hashmap is used in feature files in karate. could someone please help?


hashmap is normally never needed in karate, you should use json. I see a lot of cucumber mentioned in your code, which is absolutely not supported in karate, so please take this up with whoever asked you to use this framework. can you share more details on what you are trying to do ? karate is designed to work with JSON or CSV, you can see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78673358/143475

Thank you for the reponse Peter. The framework is from the client we are working with and hence the given structure. I am trying to write 5-8 fields in the hashmap into the an xlsx file and hence the using the hashmap.
